# Кеширование изображений из БД на локальный диск Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

Разрабатываю настольное приложение. Для работы с базой использую Entity Framework (Code First подход).

В БД есть таблица People

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,        
    [PhotoOriginal] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

В EF ей сопоставлены 2 сущности: `Person` (`id`, `Name`, `PhotoOriginal` )

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Person()
    {
        Result_question = new HashSet<Result_question>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName{get;set;}

    PhotoOriginal _PhotoOriginal;

    virtual public PhotoOriginal PhotoOriginal
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PhotoOriginal;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._PhotoOriginal != value)
            {
                this._PhotoOriginal = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("PhotoOriginal");
            }
        }

    }
```

и `PhotoOriginal` (`id`, `Image`).

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class PhotoOriginal:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }


    byte[] _Image;


    [Column("PhotoOriginal")]
    public byte[] Image
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Image;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._Image != value)
            {
                this._Image = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
    }


    virtual public Person person { get; set; }
}
```

Код из DBModel

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<PhotoOriginal>()
            .HasKey(e => e.id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasKey(e => e.id)
            .HasRequired(e => e.PhotoOriginal)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.person);        

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");            
        modelBuilder.Entity<PhotoOriginal>().ToTable("People");
    }
```

Хочу, чтобы при первом обращении к свойству `person.PhotoOriginal` изображение грузилось из базы и сохранялось на локальный диск. При последующих обращениях (после перезапуска программы тоже) EF не лез в БД, а подтягивал его с диска.
Как можно организовать подобную работу? Как модифицировать сущности? Может на какой обработчик подписаться и отлавливать обращение EF к бд? Приорететнее не писать обертку для сущностей.

Comment: Всегда, когда хочется прикрутить кеш, задумайтесь, как вы будете его инвалидировать. Ибо прикрутить кеш легко, а вот сделать для него корректную инвалидацию - в разы сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [Second Level Cache for Entity Framework](https://efcache.codeplex.com/). Он хранит данные в памяти, но можно вместо [InMemoryCache](https://efcache.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EFCache/InMemoryCache.cs) написать свою реализацию кэша, хранящего данные на диске.

Comment: Ручная инвалидация кеша, я правильно понимаю? Никакой магии? =)

Comment: @Monk - Мопед не мой... Этот кэш работает именно совместно с провайдером, никакой ручной работы, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вам надо называется кэширование. EF обеспечивает кэширование только на время жизни контекста. Ранее запрошенные из БД объекты хранятся в памяти. При уничтожении контекста, тем более при перезапуске программы кэш сбрасывается. И это правильно.
Для вашей задачи надо использовать стороннюю библиотеку или даже специализированный продукт: redis, memcached или подобные.

- https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached
- https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis